# Running the Angular2 application in the localhost

Tags: angular

I am trying to open an application from official Angular2 , but it just opens with a message "app works" without showing the actual example code that is given in the website. Any idea how I can view the exact application? To give more information when I do a right click in the application , I am getting this message:

```
 <body waid71fa0d88-5390-4b5b-a2f4-e45fa93d85e2="SA password protect entry checker">
```

Any idea how can I overcome this. I am new to Angular2 development. Want to try and tweak the existing code

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Please post the link what "application from official angular2" you are talking about

Comment: Sorry, it was a really a mistake. Failed to include package.json file , which caused this problem